# How to create a boxplot/candlestick chart?

Tags: 7, views, charts

I'm using Drupal 7.54 and I need to create a chart (scatterplot) showing also information like minimum, maximum and mean (e.g. body weight for fishes). Usually, a **boxplot** is the way to display that kind of data.

[image]

Searching through the [Comparison of Charting modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985), it seems like boxplot or candlestick charts are not supported. Only the [Easychart](https://www.drupal.org/project/easychart) module seems to have the option, but I did not manage to combine Easychart with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) (?) in order to create dynamic charts (I don't need "charts-nodes" created through the Easychart UI).

For the moment, I have created a scatterplot with [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) and then display the 3 basic stats through PHP/MySQL in the header.

I know I could also create Charts add-on (using [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)) to combine different charts (scatter for values, columns for basic stats) but I am not really pleased with the final result (see below a very first draft), for the moment (columns hiding the first scatter value, for example).

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I've never heard about a "boxplot", and I wonder if a "scatterplot" is similar to the "ScatterGraph" shown on [this page](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/sample.svg_demo) (just search for "ScatterGraph" on that page). If I'm close with such ScatterGraph, then I'd be happy to "upgrade" this comment to a real answer ... (I.e. how you can create such ScatterGraph).

Comment: Thanks Pierre for your comment. I have edited my question with illustrations. The ScatterGraph seems interesting but, considering my draft chart, do you think it could do the trick?

Comment: @Toki I've removed the question asking for general opinions on how to plot your data - please keep questions here solely focused on the Drupal aspect of your implementation. Thanks!

Comment: Of course, no problem, sorry for that @Clive and thanks for editing in the right way.